# How do I pipe output into Visual Studio Code?

Tags: pipe, stdin, visual-studio-code

I want to pipe the output of a command into a new text window in Visual Studio Code.

Normally, I'd do something like this:

```
echo foo | code
```

...but that appears to not work; Visual Studio Code launches, but it does not display the input. Is there a way to do piping on the command line?

Comment: Note: At this time there is a issue causes `echo 123 | code -` not work when you're using *Remote* extensions.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Since version 1.19.1, you can pipe your output to the current window by invoking:

```
<command> | code -
```

---

If you are using version 1.19 or earlier, you don't need the arg:

```
<command> | code
```

Comment: I had to use `<command> | code -` otherwise I'd get this message: `Run with 'code -' to read from stdin (e.g. 'ps aux | grep code | code -').`

Comment: @GuiSim for me it works without, not sure what the difference is.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: The difference is the change in v1.19.1: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_19

Comment: @CraigWalker Edited my response now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Ubuntu Gnome 17.10 (Artful Aardvark), and I run Visual Studio Code v1.19.3. Just piping to `code` is not enough to bin to stdin.

```
$ ps aux | code
Run with 'code -' to read from stdin (e.g. 'ps aux | grep code | code -').
```

You have to add the `-` operator:

```
$ ps aux | code -
```

That's working and opens a new text tab filled by the command output.

Comment: This changed to require `code -` as of 1.19.1: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_19

Answer (score 2):

As of September 2016, it does not appear to be supported, but there's an open issue to implement it:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6161

Comment: This answer is outdated and not really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When I use the accepted answer, the console is blocked until I close the corresponding tab in VS Code. Since I often want to keep the tab open in VS Code while I keep using the console, I came up with this workaround:

```
ls > t; code t; rm t
```

It redirects to file `t` in the current directory, tells VS Code to open that file, and then deletes it.  You will see the contents of the file in VS Code in a tab labeled `t (deleted)`.

A slight delay (1 second works for me) is needed if VS Code isn't already open:

```
ls > t; code t; sleep 1; rm t
```

Notes

- I tested this on Windows 10 using either Git Bash or PowerShell 7.
- Of course, be careful with the name you use for the throwaway file so you don't overwrite a real file.

Edit: I made a function for this to throw in my PowerShell profile.

```
Function Out-Code {
    do {
        $filename = New-Guid
    } while (Test-Path $filename)
    $input > $filename
    code $filename
    Start-Sleep 1
    Remove-Item $filename
}
Set-Alias oc Out-Code
```

Usage

```
ls | oc
```

Comment: Unfortunately this bug that `code -` does not exit when the input stream is closed or reaches end has not been fixed yet although it was reported multiple times. For example: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66600

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [*Copy/Pipe from Terminal*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=babakks.vscode-copy-from-terminal) extension and use `cp2code` or `tee2code` (the `tee2code` doesn't terminate the piping chain) in the terminal like this:

```bash
ls ~ | cp2code
ls ~ | tee2code | sort
```

It opens a new document with the data piped into that. If you have multiple VS Code windows, it'll show you the copied data on that window you did run the command.